# ngMap center is not working properly in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ng-map

I am using ngMap in angular for google map integration.

below are my html code

```
<map ng-transclude class='google-map' center="map.center"> 
    <marker position="marker.position" options="marker.options"></marker>
</map>
```

my controller code is

```
//response get from server side 
var onResponse = function(response){
    $scope.workshop = response;
    mapCenter(response.latitude, response.longitude);
```

};

```
function mapCenter(latitude, longitude) {

    $scope.map = {
      center: [latitude, longitude]
    };

    $scope.marker = {
      position: [latitude, longitude],
      options: function(){
        return {
          draggable: true
        }
      }
    };

};
```

In this case map is display but center of map is not display properly it gets to the right side.

If I put below code outside function with dummy lat and long then it's working fine but I can't get dynamic lat and long value outside this function that's why I need to put this code in function.

```
$scope.map = {
          center: [18.9750, 72.8258]
        };
```

Please help me for solution.

Answer (score 1):

you can check it

```
center="{{map.center}}"
```

and set your data in `$timeout` function. may be angular digest problem if your latitude, longitude perfect

```
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.map = {
      center: [latitude, longitude]
    };
});
```

Comment: I tried with center="map.center" as well as center="{{map.center}}" but not work for me

Comment: check your `response.latitude` and `response.longitude` values

Comment: yes I checked everything is all right. Problem with scope when I declare scope.map outside function with dummy data then it's working.

Comment: please how can I calculate the center dynamically if I'm displaying a polygon on the map?

Answer (score 0):

actually you are overwriting our `$scope.map`.

Please update

```
function mapCenter(latitude, longitude) {

                $scope.map.center =[latitude, longitude];
                $scope.marker.position = [latitude, longitude];
            };
```

Also use  `dorebuildall="true"` propeprty